# Writing to text file in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to do some operations on images and write some data into a txt file.Here is what I am doing for one image-

```
clc;
image=imread('im.png');
.... %do some operations
....
....
fileID=fopen('first.txt','w');
....  %write onto the txt file
....
fclose(fileID);
```

But I want to do this for many images.I have stored all the images in a folder.Also, I want to continue writing in the same text file immediately after where I left off for the previous image.How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's pretty simple.  Use a loop and loop over all of your images, do your processing on it, then append to the text file.  What'll be easier is that you just open the file for your text ONCE, write for as many times as you have images, then finally close it.

Something like this:

```
folder = ...; %// Place folder here - Example: folder = fullfile('D:', 'images'); 
fileID=fopen('first.txt','w'); %// Open up the file for writing
f = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.png')); %// look for all PNG files in this folder
for idx = 1 : numel(f)
    filename = fullfile(folder, f(idx).name); %// Get the file name
    im = imread(filename); %// Read the image in
    .... %do some operations
    ....
    ....

    ....  %write onto the txt file
    ....
    fprintf(fileID, '\n\n'); %// Put two carriage returns to make way for next file
end
fclose(fileID);
```

The function [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) scans for all files that match a particular expression.  In your case, you want to find all PNG files in a particular folder of your choosing.  I assume that this is stored in the variable `folder`.  We then open up the file first before we do anything to the images, then loop over each of the found images with `dir`.  Take note that when you use `dir`, it only finds the **relative** paths to the files (i.e. just the names themselves).  If you want to locate where the actual images are, you need the **absolute** paths, which is why we use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html).

So, for each PNG image that's in the folder, load it in, do your processing on it, write to your file and I make sure that I put in two carriage returns to separate each result.  You repeat this for each PNG image until you exhaust all of them from the folder.  Once you're done, you close the text file.

## Minor note

[`image`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) is an actual function in MATLAB that visualizes a matrix of values as an image with a specified colour map.  You should probably rename this variable to something else so you don't overshadow the function in case other scripts / functions you write use this function.

Comment: Thanks but I have doubt.The folder has to be something like this-
`folder='D:\images';`  or `folder='D:\\images'`?

Comment: @LifeIsGood - That's the beauty of `fullfile`.  You would do this: `folder = fullfile('D:', 'images');`  This way, the "slash" handling is automatically handled for whatever operating system you choose to run the code.

Comment: Just curious,if I have both png and jpeg files,should I do this-
`f = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.png','*.jpg'));`

Comment: @LifeIsGood - Ah, if you want two, you would need to call `dir` for both of them separately, then concatenate them together.  Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828345/how-to-load-all-files-from-a-directory-of-two-different-types-in-matlab/29828539#29828539 .  MATLAB's `dir` command doesn't support searching for more than one type of file.  It's either one type, or every file in a folder.  If you want two files, you would use two `dir` calls then concatenate the results together and run a single `for` loop.

Comment: @LifeIsGood - BTW, thanks for the accept!  Let me know if you can't get the two type variant working.  If not, I can modify the post above.